# How to interpret density of states and band structure of a material?

Tags: vasp, band-structure, reference-request, ab-initio-calculations, density-of-states

I am new on the VASP platform, and have learned how to calculate any material's DOS and Band structure.

However, I don't know how to interpret these properties. Can you recommend resources that explain the basics of DOS and band structure interpretation?

Comment: Can you state which kind of analysis program are you looking for? Are you looking for GUI-based or script-based like python?

Comment: I am using p4v to analyze Band and DOS, but I need reading material that helps me understand the band and DOS graph and theory. @TaraMishra

Comment: There a number of questions on this site that have discussed how to interpret DOS and band structures: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1791/properties-that-can-be-deduced-from-band-structure-and-dos/2396#2396, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/what-is-the-difference-between-dos-and-pdos, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4555/what-does-a-density-of-states-dos-plot-show (and many more under the tags for those properties). I think these cover the basic ideas and any more detail would probably require reading a book on solid state physics.

Comment: @MauleshVALA were the links in the comment by Tyberius helpful?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.